# Chunk a map with Intel TBB parallel_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I want to traverse my `std::map` in parallel with `parallel_for`.
As the tutorial says, we cannot randomly access it, so I chose `parallel_for_each`.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map_;  // student name, student age

tbb::parallel_for_each(map_.begin(), map_.end(), [&](const auto& item) {  
    processOne worker;
    worker(item.first, map_.size());
});
```

But it seems that `parallel_for_each` will not chunk the map into subtasks, so it is quite slow.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, map_.size(), 10000), [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r) {
        ...
});
```

Comment: consider to use a `std::vector<std::pair<Key,Value>>` instead of the map

Comment: I tried but it is twice as slow as `parellel_for_each`, weird.

Comment: You can get better results with tbb::concurrent_hash_map if it suits you ... or with array where you actually keep boost::intrusive::set elements. That std::map just isn't designed to be very efficient with lot of data, even when single threaded.